# WordPress responds to the ajax request with readyState 1, 2, 3 before responding with 4

Tags: ajax

```
readyState= 1
this.status= 0
readyState= 2
this.status= 200
readyState= 3
this.status= 200
readyState= 4
this.status= 200
```

These are the responses I get, and in the end it finally responds with 4 and 200. My php function just echoes `"hello from php"`. I used `ob_clean()` before echo and `wp_die()` as per Codex recommendations because it said there may be unnecessary responses mixed in with ajax but still didn't help at all.

Comment: can you edit your question to add more context?  Where is it making AJAX requests to? REST API/admin-ajax.php? Can you include the handler code? It's near impossible to answer this with just the information available and there is no code to debug. Note that the Codex was retired several years ago and replaced by https://developer.wordpress.org/

Comment: WordPress isn’t responding multiple times with each of these at all. This is just how the browser/JavaScript reports the current status of the request: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState What actual problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thank you! I'm trying simply send an email from a contact form on the front page. I'm using vanilla JS for ajax. If this is how browsers/JS behave I can probably just disregard readyState 1-3